# Show PHP array of UNIX timestamps as string in a particular format

Tags: php, formatting, date

I currently have this code:

```
$dates = array();
foreach($data['sc_event_dates'] as $date) {
    if($date > time()) {
        $dates[] = date( empty($dates) ? "D d M": "d M", $date);
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $dates);
```

And it displays something like this:

```
Thu 11 Aug, 18 Aug, 25 Aug, 01 Sep, 08 Sep, 15 Sep
```

But what I need to do group the dates of each month so the output would look like this:

```
Thu 11, 18, 25 Aug, 01, 08, 15 Sep
```

`$data['sc_event_dates']` holds an array of unix timestamps and is ordered in `ascending` order.

Also dates that are before current time need to be ignored.

Here is some example data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1313020800
    [1] => 1313625600
    [2] => 1314230400
    [3] => 1314835200
    [4] => 1315440000
    [5] => 1316044800
)
```

Can any one help alter my code, or produce new code, to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
foreach($data['sc_event_dates'] as $key => $date) {
    if($date > time()) {

        $next = ++$key;
        $format = 'd';

        if( empty($dates) ) {

            $format = 'D '.$format;
        }

        if( !isset( $data['sc_event_dates'][$next] ) || date('n', $date) != date('n', $data['sc_event_dates'][$next]) ) {

            $format .= ' M';
        }

        $dates[] = date( $format, $date);
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd a simple state machine to keep track of which month is being displayed and adjust output as need be.

```
$prev_month = null;
foreach(... as $date) {
   if ($date < time()) {
      continue;
   }
   $day = date('D', $date);
   $day_num = date('d', $date);
   $month = date('M');
   if ($prev_month != $month) {
       echo $month, ' ';
       $prev_month = $month;
       $sep = '';
   }
   echo $day_num, $sep;
   $sep = ', ';
}
```

not tested, YMMV, etc...